# Arrange the array in required sequence

Tags: php, arrays

I Have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [COMPANY NAME] => 1
            [LPO NUMBER] => PO1
            [LPO DATE] => 2011-04-13 10:08:37
            [LPO AMT] => 1000
            [PENDING AMT] => 1000
            [PRIORITY] => 1
            [AMOUNT] => 200
            [BENEFICIARY NAME] => Self
            [PAYMENT AS] => 1
            [VENDOR NAME] => 0
            [FINAL PAYMENT] => 
            [doc_id] => 2
            [Vendor Name] => Dept. of Economic Development.
            [Reference Number] => PR_XHA_210
            [Pay Cheque Number] => N/A
            [Paid] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [COMPANY NAME] => 1
            [LPO NUMBER] => PO1
            [LPO DATE] => 2011-04-13 10:08:37
            [LPO AMT] => 1000
            [PENDING AMT] => 800
            [PRIORITY] => 1
            [AMOUNT] => 800
            [BENEFICIARY NAME] => Self
            [PAYMENT AS] => 1
            [VENDOR NAME] => 0
            [FINAL PAYMENT] => 
            [doc_id] => 3
            [Vendor Name] => Dept. of Economic Development.
            [Reference Number] => PR_XHA_211
            [Pay Cheque Number] => N/A
            [Paid] => 0
        )

)
```

I need to arrange array in my required sequence of indexes which is like

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Reference Number] => PR_XHA_210
            [Vendor Name] => Dept. of Economic Development.
            [BENEFICIARY NAME] => Self
            [LPO DATE] => 2011-04-13 10:08:37
            [LPO NUMBER] => PO1
            [LPO AMT] => 1000
            [Paid] => 0
            [AMOUNT] => 200
            [doc_id] => 2
            [doc_id] => 2
            [Pay Cheque Number] => N/A

        )
```

How It can be done?
Pls Help...

Comment: Arrange sounds weird, unless you use `foreach` or `next()` the resulting array seems to be just smaller. If you ignore the duplicate invalid key `doc_id`

Comment: Just curious...if you're using an associative array, why does key order matter? What's the point of even having keys then?

Comment: My need is To Iterate the array such that every "<td>" gets its value required specific value, like wise here first "<td>" must have "Reference Number" as first Value

Comment: After reading the comments I am not quite sure I've understood your question right. Sorry, English is not my mother tounge.

Comment: @OmTheEternity Ok. But just FYI, PHP is somewhat of an outlier in that it maintains associative array key order. Order is not guaranteed in similar structures in most other languages.

Comment: Now I changed my solution. Look at it again. Basically you just need a normal array, then you can iterate over it with for loops and always keep the order as you wanted it.

Comment: u want same key in desired array ...see `[doc_id] => 2
            [doc_id] => 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
$keys = array(
    'Reference Number',
    'Vendor Name',
    ...
);

$reordered = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $new_item = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $new_item[$key] = $item[$key];
    }
    $reordered[] = $new_item;
}
```

This will create a new array `$reordered` which holds all your rows, with the keys reordered according to the order defined in `$keys`.

Alternatively you could reorder your array in-place using `uksort` and a callback function (again, untested).

```
function sort_keys($a, $b) {
    static $keys = array(
        'Reference Number',
        'Vendor Name',
        ...
    );

    return array_search($a, $keys) - array_search($b, $keys);
}

foreach ($array as &$item) {
    uksort($item, 'sort_keys');
}
```

A third option is to leave your array alone but to edit your view code:

```
$keys = array(
    'Reference Number',
    'Vendor Name',
    ...
);

foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        printf('<tr><th>%s</th><td>%s</td></tr>',
            htmlspecialchars($key),
            htmlspecialchars($item[$key]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to be clever with actually sorting the array, but the easiest way is to simply recreate it:

```
$rearrangedArray = array(
    'Reference Number' => $oldArray['Reference Number'],
    'Vendor Name'      => $oldArray['Vendor Name'],
    ...
);
```

It seems like a very non-sensical thing to do though. Either your array is numerically indexed and ordered, or you're using an associative array. Requiring both is plain weird.

---

> *My need is To Iterate the array such that every "`<td>`" gets its value required specific value, like wise here first "`<td>`" must have "Reference Number" as first Value*

In that case you should just create your table explictly so:

```
<tr>
    <td>Reference Number:</td> <td><?php echo $array['Reference Number']; ?></td>
    <td>Vendor Name:</td>      <td><?php echo $array['Vendor Name']; ?></td>
    ...
</tr>
```

Comment: Ordered associative arrays are not weird at all in PHP. It's why functions like [`ksort()`](http://nl.php.net/ksort) exist.

Comment: @Sander True. They are not weird *in* PHP. The fact that PHP bothers to maintain key order is weird when *compared with other languages*.

Comment: @Sander `ksort` is useful for sorting *values* using the keys as criterium, which is not all that uncommon. Requiring non-numeric *keys* to have a specific order *is* somewhat uncommon. I know both are basically the same, but the use case is quite different.

Comment: Lisp has alists, Python and Java have ordered dictionaries. Perl has indexed hashes (as a module). They're all ordered associative arrays (ordered maps, really). They're quite common.

Answer (score 1):

Read your requirement from the comments,
do not order your associative array. Instead do a cleaner thing like :

1. Have a integer index to associative array key mapping. eg.

   **$myIndexes = Array("Reference Number","Vendor Name","BENEFICIARY NAME" ....);**
  2.

for($i=0;$i< count($dataArray);$i++)
   {

```
      $myCurrentKey = $myIndexes[$i];
      $myCurrentData = $dataArray[$myCurrentKey];
      echo "<td>".$myCurrentData."</td>";
 }
```

While printing your `<td>` sequentially, fetch a keyName from $myIndexes, and then fetch the value from your data array.

Answer (score 1):

You could create functions that make use of `array_splice()` to reorder array elements. It's most likely better to just rebuild the array how you want it, but just for variety of answers, here it is:

```
<?php

// $input  (Array) - the array containing the element
// $index (int) - the index of the element you need to move

function moveUp($input,$index) {
      $new_array = $input;

       if((count($new_array)>$index) && ($index>0)){
                 array_splice($new_array, $index-1, 0, $input[$index]);
                 array_splice($new_array, $index+1, 1);
             } 

       return $new_array;
}

function moveDown($input,$index) {
       $new_array = $input;

       if(count($new_array)>$index) {
                 array_splice($new_array, $index+2, 0, $input[$index]);
                 array_splice($new_array, $index, 1);
             } 

       return $new_array;
 }  

$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

$newinput = moveUp($input, 2);
// $newinput is array("red", "blue", "green", "yellow")

$input = moveDown($newinput, 1);
// $input is array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow")

?>
```

Then simply call these functions on your array until the order is how you like it.

Answer (score 0):

because your array is quite long, I show it with a simpler example. This is $your_array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [COMPANY NAME] => 1
            [LPO NUMBER] => PO1
         )
    [0] => Array
        (
            [AMOUNT] => 200
            [doc_id] => 2
         )
)
```

put it together with the following code:

```
$together = array(
  $your_array[1]['AMOUNT'],
  $your_array[0]['COMPANY NAME'],
  $your_array[0]['LPO NUMBER'],
  $your_array[1]['doc_id']
);
```

I hope with that example in hand you can fill out the rest by yourself.